# Migrate a Craft site to Craft Commerce

Tags: ecommerce

We have a Craft client who would like to add a store/cart to their website. Is it possible to migrate a Craft CMS site to Craft Commerce?

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that Craft Commerce is a plugin for Craft CMS, which answers my question and definitely makes me happy!